# Firebase Deploy to Cloud Firestore using SDK 2

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to deploy functions to Firestore using SDK 2.X After I upgraded from version 1.x I get an error I cannot figure out.
All previous deployments with SDK 1.x, using the same node.js version worked.

```
From what I can see there is a lot of modules not found, and they are:
import * as analytics from './providers/analytics';
import * as auth from './providers/auth';
import * as crashlytics from './providers/crashlytics';
import * as database from './providers/database';
import * as firestore from './providers/firestore';
import * as https from './providers/https';
import * as pubsub from './providers/pubsub';
import * as storage from './providers/storage';
import { HttpsFunction } from './cloud-functions';

Log file from npm:
info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\mbhscssV1\\mbh-functions\\functions',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle functions@~prebuild: functions@
6 info lifecycle functions@~build: functions@
7 verbose lifecycle functions@~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle functions@~build: PATH: C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\mbhscssV1\mbh-functions\functions\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\scssa\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;%NVM_HOME%;%NVM_SYMLINK%;C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;D:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;D:\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;%DASHLANE_DLL_DIR%;C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle functions@~build: CWD: C:\mbhscssV1\mbh-functions\functions
10 silly lifecycle functions@~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'tsc' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ build: `tsc`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\scssa\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd C:\mbhscssV1\mbh-functions
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--prefix" "C:\\mbhscssV1\\mbh-functions\\functions" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.11.2
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error functions@ build: `tsc`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the functions@ build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Any help VERY much appreciated.

Comment: I have solved this issue.

Comment: Would you mind answering your question with your answer and mark it as resolved ? Other people might be interested.

Comment: Solved. Moved all files to a new directory and reinstalled everything and then it worked. Conclusion on Windows 10, upgrade does not work properly.